# Converting to int

Tags: c#

I encounter a error when I try to convert a string variable which is read from a text file to int.
How can I convert the number that is read from a text to int?

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class FileWriter
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int a = 6;
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"D:\asd.txt");
            using (writer)
            {
               writer.WriteLine(a);
            }
        }
    }
}
class FileReader
{
     static void Second()
     {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\asd.txt");
        using (reader)
        {

            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(line);

           }

            );

    }

    }
```

Comment: Upload also the error you are getting. In the future, it helps people (us) understand, what is the problem. In this context, format of the file  is important too. So maybe try to update you question.

Comment: Please edit your code so that it is readable and compilable

Comment: yes and also try to write proper question as it is not that clear

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert String to Int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019793/how-can-i-convert-string-to-int)

Comment: `if (int.TryParse(line, out int a)) {/*line is a valid integer which is parsed into a*/} else {/*line doesn't represent integer*/}`

Comment: Review note: initialize `reader` and `writer` as part of the `using` block, not before it.

Comment: [There](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1019793/2716623) [is](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21663357/2716623) [so](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2344411/2716623) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42001743/2716623) [duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45523185/2716623) [on](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16790337/2716623) [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37814186/2716623) :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Int32.TryParse` as mention in below code.

```
 int no = 0;
 string number = "6";
 Int32.TryParse(number, out no);
```

Answer (score 3):

You use `Int32.TryParse` it's safe

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this, with `TryParse` and `Trim()` to remove any whitespaces.

```
class FileReader
{
    static void Second()
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\asd.txt");

        using(reader)
        {
            int number;
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            bool success = Int32.TryParse(value.Trim(), out number);
            if (success) {
                Console.WriteLine("Number is:" + number);
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("Could not parse the number");
            }
        }
    }
}
```